# Routing multiple forms on the same page to different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering whether it was possible to have two forms on the same page which maps to two different controllers in a rails application

In my routes file, I mapped the root route to new action of the user controllers

```
root to: 'users#new'
```

The new page basically renders a signup form.

[image: sign-up form]

On the header of the same page, I happen to have a 
login in form which I am intending on routing to another controller

[image: login-form]

The signup form currently re-directs to the proper controller#action but was wondering if I could direct the login to a whole new controller/action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry if mistakenly understood your question.

If you want to have multiple forms (or links) to differente controller(or same controller and just another action) on the same page, there should be no problem, since the path to the action is explicitly passed on to the form:

`<%= form_for path_to_controller_action_path(id,...), etc. %>`

or for links:

`<%= link_to "label", path_to_controller_action(id,...) %>`